# Unable to understand tf.nn.raw_rnn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-slim

In the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn) of `tf.nn.raw_rnn` we have emit structure as the third output of `loop_fn` when the `loop_fn` is run for the first time.

Later on the emit_structure is used to copy `tf.zeros_like(emit_structure)` to the minibatch entries that are finished by `emit = tf.where(finished, tf.zeros_like(emit_structure), emit)`.

my lack of understanding or lousy documentation on google's part is: emit structure is `None` so `tf.where(finished, tf.zeros_like(emit_structure), emit)` is going to throw a ValueError as `tf.zeros_like(None)` does so. Can somebody please fill in what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the doc is rather confusing in this place. If you look at the internals of `tf.nn.raw_rnn`, the key term there is **"in pseudo-code"**, so the example in the doc isn't accurate.

The exact source code looks like this (may differ depending on your tensorflow version):

```py
if emit_structure is not None:
  flat_emit_structure = nest.flatten(emit_structure)
  flat_emit_size = [emit.shape if emit.shape.is_fully_defined() else
                    array_ops.shape(emit) for emit in flat_emit_structure]
  flat_emit_dtypes = [emit.dtype for emit in flat_emit_structure]
else:
  emit_structure = cell.output_size
  flat_emit_size = nest.flatten(emit_structure)
  flat_emit_dtypes = [flat_state[0].dtype] * len(flat_emit_size)
```

So it handles the case when `emit_structure is None` and simply takes the value `cell.output_size`. That's why nothing really breaks.